# invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive] on passing array

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am new to C++ language and I have no idea of pointers and their usage. I'm facing the error `"[Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]"` while compiling in line:

```c
cout << midd (ax [10], asize) << endl;
```

This is the code:

```c
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
double midd(int arr[10], int size);

int main() {
    int ax[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int asize = 10;
    cout << midd(ax[10], asize) << endl;
}

double midd(int arr[10], int size) {
    int acount = 0;
    int mid1;
    int mid2;
    int amid = size / 2;

    double mid = 0.0;

    while (acount < 10) {
        if (acount == amid) {
            mid1 = arr[acount];
        }
        else if (acount == (mid + 1)) {
            mid2 = arr[acount];
        }
        ++acount;
    }    
    mid = (mid1 + mid2) / 2.0;
    return mid;
}
```

Comment: Please don't spam language tags. Your code is not C but C++ which is a different language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `midd(int arr[10],int size);` is expecting int* and you are trying to pass int value ( ax[10] which is also ERROR : ax has only 10 elements and you try to use 11th ), and compiler can not convert `int` to `int*` so it shows "[Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]".

To make this program correct you have to make this change.

- Replace `cout<< midd (ax[10], asize );` with `cout<< midd (ax, asize );`

  -now pointer of ax (`int*`) is passed so `midd()` will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Change the function call

```
cout << midd(ax, asize) << endl;
```

and declaration

```
double midd(int arr[], int size) { ... }
```

or go the C++ way: `std::vector` or `std::array`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

double midd(array<int, 10> a) {
    int mid = a.size() / 2;
    return (a[mid] + a[mid + 1]) / 2.0;
}

int main() {
    array<int, 10> ax = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    cout << midd(ax) << endl;
}
```

Comment: @Bob__ the latest edit did not reflect in the answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a pointer to the first element of array. Change `midd (ax [10], asize )` to `midd (ax, asize )`.

In function signature

```
double midd(int arr[10],int size);
```

parameter `int arr[10]` is equivalent to `int *arr`

```
double midd(int *arr,int size);
```

Therefore, `midd` expects its first argument of the type `int *`. In function call `midd (ax, asize )`, `ax` will decay to `int *`.

Comment: i wrote another with mostly same passing of array

that does not requires pointer passing so why dose this one ??

Comment: @drainzerrr; Didn't get you?